# Updating model with values from formgroup

Tags: angular, forms, angular7

I have a formgroup that I populate with data from my model. Example:

```
inputForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.inputForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        name: [this.myObject.name, Validators.required]
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});
 }
```

This will show myObject.name in the input field, which is what I want. When I then type in a new value and submit, the model is not updated with the new value. I know this is expected behaviour, but is there a way to bind the input value to myObject.name so that it updates automatically or do I have to manually retrieve the new value from the formgroup and assign it?

Answer (score 0):

formBuilder does NOT accept {updateOn}, you must use newFormGroup directly and create a new FormControl

```
this.inputForm = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormControl(this.myObject.name, Validators.required)
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});
```

(personally I like this way more than the use of formBuilder)

But this does NOT update your object, it just updates the inputForm. To update the object you need something like:

```
this.myObject=this.inputForm.value
```